# Wait for routes and database to initialize before running Mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, mocha.js

I have a NodeJS app that connects to a Mongo database and then initializes all the routes once the connection has been established. I want to add some Mocha tests using a server and `supertest` for test requests. However, to retrieve the server from the `test.js` file, I need to `require()` the main file and get the server variable from it. When I try to use it however, it complains that the variable is undefined, as the database hasn't loaded and the routes haven't been initialised.

`main.js (extract)`

```
// This is a custom mongo module that connects using my db string
// It stores the DB as a variable in another file, which is later retrieved by the route handlers using mongo.GetDB()

mongo.ConnectToDB(function(err, dbo){
    if(err) throw err;

    require("./api")(app);
    require("./admin")(app);
    require("./routes")(app);
});

// This obviously doesn't work, as it's outside of the callback
module.exports.server = app.listen(4500);
```

`server.test.js (extract)`

```
describe("loading express", (done) => {
    let server;
    beforeEach(() => {
        // The server is returned, but none of the routes are included
        server = require("../main").server;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        server.close();
    });

    // ...
});
```

Is there any way to wait for the database and the routes to initialize **before** the `server` variable is retrieved and the Mocha tests continue?

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Thank you for your help, I shall see what I can do.

Comment: Could you please add that as an answer so I can mark it as answered @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have `main.js` export a `Promise` instead, something like:

```
module.exports.serverPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  mongo.ConnectToDB(function(err, dbo){
    if(err) reject(err);
    require("./api")(app);
    require("./admin")(app);
    require("./routes")(app);

    resolve(app.listen(4500));
  });
});
```

Then, after importing it, you can use it after calling `.then` on the `Promise`